# .net core worker porcess on virtual kubelet on ACI ..how to start the job?

Tags: .net-core, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

I am creating a .net core worker process to run some background tasks. This job will run as an Azure Container instance hosted on a virtual kubelet of an existing AKS cluster as mentioned in https://medium.com/@fbeltrao/scheduling-jobs-in-aks-with-virtual-kubelet-97f59c466c2d

The problem is this job is not a timer/schedule based job and will run when a particular event happens (like a http post). I am not sure how to invoke this job. is my approach correct?

PS: This job will process around 25k rows and each row processing consists of lots of business logic and multiple DB updates.

Comment: I think the job should be a continuously running job, and when you access it and send the order then it operates the order and that's it.

Comment: Hi Charles, unfortunately the requirement is that the job (long-running) should b triggererd by an event rather than timer based